# Replacing values in dataframe by values from other rows by "target row"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do the following: When the value of 'content' is NaN, replace its value from that of the target row. Below is my code which does that by iterating over all rows, but it is ugly and slow. I suspect there should be a more elegant/fast way to do this with mask, so I figured someone may inspire me on this:

```
Inputs:

import pandas as pd
d = {'content': [1, 3, None, 6, 1, 59, None], 'target': [0,1,0,2,4,5,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index,'content']!=df.loc[index,'content']: # To detect NaN
        df.loc[index,'content']=df.loc[df.loc[index,'target'],'content']
print(df)

outputs:
       content  target
    0      1.0       0
    1      3.0       1
    2      NaN       0
    3      6.0       2
    4      1.0       4
    5     59.0       5
    6      NaN       4

       content  target
    0      1.0       0
    1      3.0       1
    2      1.0       0
    3      6.0       2
    4      1.0       4
    5     59.0       5
    6      1.0       4
```

Thanks in advance!

Note: Only when the content of the row is "NaN", the content should be changed to that of the target row.

Additional Question: Can I do the same thing, whenever the content is 59 or 6? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops! I just realized your previous code doesn't do what I asked!
 
Supposedly row 3 should have the content of row 2 (which is 3.0), because df.loc[3,'target']=2 (points to row 2).

Row 6 should have content of row 5 (which is 59), because df.loc[6,'target']=5 (points to row 5)

Comment: Would you be able to do the same thing for this table?
    d = {'content': [1, 3, None, 6, 1, 59, None], 'target': [0,1,0,2,4,5,4]} 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
    df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `fillna`

```
df.content=df.content.fillna(df.target)
df
Out[268]: 
   content  target
0      1.0       0
1      3.0       1
2      6.0       0
3      2.0       2
4      1.0       4
5     59.0       5
6      5.0       5
```

EDIT

```
df.ffill()
Out[487]: 
   content  target
0      1.0       0
1      3.0       1
2      6.0       0
3      6.0       2
4      1.0       4
5     59.0       5
6     59.0       5
```

I guess you need this

```
df.content.reindex(df.target)
Out[492]: 
target
0     1.0
1     3.0
0     1.0
2     6.0
4     1.0
5    59.0
5    59.0
Name: content, dtype: float64
```

After assign it back

```
df.content=df.content.reindex(df.target).values
df
Out[494]: 
   content  target
0      1.0       0
1      3.0       1
2      1.0       0
3      6.0       2
4      1.0       4
5     59.0       5
6     59.0       5
```

Let me edit again

```
df.content.fillna(df.content.reindex(df.target).reset_index(drop=True))
Out[508]: 
0     1.0
1     3.0
2     1.0
3     6.0
4     1.0
5    59.0
6     1.0
Name: content, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! What if I want to replace the values whenever its content is 6.0 by its target? I suppose we can start with the boolean mask df['content']==6?

Comment: @ShaoRanHuang `df.loc[df['content']==6,'content']=df.target`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but seems like it changes the 'content' of row 2 to 0 instead of 1, which is the content of the target of row 2.

Comment: @ShaoRanHuang check your input df, when content ==6 target ==0

Comment: Oops! I just realized your previous code doesn't do what I asked!
 
Supposedly row 3 should have the content of row 2 (which is 3.0), because df.loc[3,'target']=2 (points to row 2).

Row 6 should have content of row 5 (which is 59), because df.loc[6,'target']=5 (points to row 5)

Comment: @ShaoRanHuang you mean , My answer or my comment ?

Comment: It may be easier to understand what I want to do by running the code that I provided. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Your answer. For filling the NAs

Comment: I see! I guess I posed the question in a wrong way, I want the target index to not be only the previous one, but it can be anything. Let me update my question.

Comment: @ShaoRanHuang did you see this one ? `df.content=df.content.reindex(df.target).values`

Comment: The content is only changed when the content of the row is certain thing, let's say NaN or 59. This doesn't do what is mentioned in the question. Sorry!

Comment: @ShaoRanHuang updated again, please consider do not change your original question in your next post

Comment: Thanks a lot! Oh I didn't realize it causes inconvenience to the previous answers. Sorry!